# data.frame rowwise calculation on a column

Tags: r

I have the following code and need your help to advice if this is the best approach or a faster way.
Currently its taking me 20+ mins to get it completed.

```
library(dplyr)
email_address=c('abc@gmail.com', 'pqr@gmail.com','xyz@gmail.com')
working_df<-as.data.frame(email_address, stringsAsFactors =F )
# 40K rows
master_email_address=c('abc@gmail.com', 'pqr@gmail.com','xyz@gmail.com','abc@gmail.com.au', 'team-pqr@gmail.com','cnn_xyz@gmail.com')
master_df<-as.data.frame(master_email_address, stringsAsFactors =F)
# 90K rows

get_string2<- function(in_col_value){
  temp_str<-NA
  temp_str<-paste(grep(in_col_value, master_df$master_email_address, value=T), collapse = ",")  
  return(temp_str)
}

working_df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(fuzzy_domain=as.character(get_string2(email_address)))
```

working_df: hold few email addresses.
master_df: contains all possible email addresses, some with prefix, suffix etc

I want to check the email_address from **working_df** if they exists in some form/format in **master_df** and return be a comma separated string with those possible values.
I have tried the same loop with apply and its almost same performance.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can speed this up simply (by 4 times) by using the following:

```
apply(working_df, 1, get_string2)
```

A test on my MacBook Air with `microbenchmark` yielded a mean of around 185 μs for `times=1000L`; the other method yielded a mean of around 742 μs for `times=1000L`.

Also, you can eliminate the `temp_str <- NA` as it is not needed. You will return an empty string when no match is found, regardless.

Comment: Thank you.. let me do the same and revert back to this thread.